# First and last color in sampled colorbar

Tags: tikz-pgf

to recreate a plot within TIKZ, I'm using the viridis colormap with sampled colors option, which works almost perfectly.
My problem is that I get the correct number of steps, but the first and last color always differ from the one of the continuous map. Therefore, the highest value is green and not the desired yellow.

Is there a way to set the first and last color used in the sampled colormap?
Or is the interpolation function known, which calculated the sampled color values from viridis?

Best regards,

ps

Edit: Some code to illustrate my problem below

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[colormap name=viridis,
               colorbar]  
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[colormap name=viridis,
               colorbar,
               colorbar sampled, colorbar style={samples=4}, colormap access=piecewise const]  
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[colormap name=viridis,
               colorbar,
               colorbar sampled, colorbar style={samples=8}, colormap access=piecewise const]  
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[colormap name=viridis,
               colorbar,
               colorbar sampled, colorbar style={samples=12}, colormap access=piecewise const]  
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Would `\begin{axis}[ colormap={example}{
        samples of colormap=(4 of viridis)
    },
               colorbar,
               colorbar sampled, colorbar style={samples=4}, colormap access=piecewise const]  
  \end{axis}` be a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workaround:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 colormap={example}{ samples of colormap=(4 of viridis) }, 
 colorbar, 
 colorbar sampled, 
 colorbar style={samples=4}, 
 colormap access=piecewise const
] 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]